# Hiding Navigation bar and Status Bar without flickering

Tags: android, hide, navigationbar

I am working on an Android App. I have a main_activity ,which shows a UI screen.
I have hidden the Navigation Bar and Status bar for this activity using the following code :-

```
decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        // This work only for android 4.4+
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);

        // Code below is to handle presses of Volume up or Volume down.
        // Without this, after pressing volume buttons, the navigation bar will
        // show up and won't hide
        decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                if((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0)
                {
                    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                }
            }
        });
```

It works Fine . When i launch my app , my main_activity gets called and it launches the app in full screen . But when it is launched the STATUS_BAR and NAVIGATION_BAR are momentarily shown and then they get hidden.
THIS IS  OK FOR main_activity.

BUT Now my main activity launches another activity .
basically i click a Setting Button in my app , which launches a new activity.
This new activity also needs to be in full screen . So i use the above mentioned code snippet to make it full screen.
It goes full screen . But the NAVIGATION_BAR and STATUS_BAR are again momentarily shown . THIS IS NOT OK from user's perspective . Because my main_activity has already hidden the BARS ,so new activity should not show them even momentarily.

I donot know how to achieve this . Your help is appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Here is how i launch my new_activity:-

```
private void shownewscreen() //new screen is basically setting screen
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.setClass(this, newscreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I use following code in the onCreate method of new activity to hide both the bars :-

protected void makeWindowWithoutStatusNaviBar() {

```
decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        | View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN;
// This work only for android 4.4+
// Code below is to handle presses of Volume up or Volume down.
// Without this, after pressing volume buttons, the navigation bar will
// show up and won't hide
decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
        if((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0)
        {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
        }
    }
});
```

On Windows' focus change also i use following code in new activity:-

```
     onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus) {
       super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
}
```

Comment: Try to use fragments instead of several activities

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? i have the same problem..

Comment: Yes. I Use Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen in my manifest file for my main activity.
And in setting activity, call makeWindowWithOutStatusBar before setContentView.

In makeWindowWithoutStatusNaviBar method , do not use all flags. 
use only  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

Comment: @Lichtamberg does it work for you